# CSS Float multiple left-floated elements and one right floated

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm having a bit of trouble with floats. I'm playing with a site that I want to make a bit responsive using media queries for varying browser widths. As it sits, the page displays with the flow of the HTML, but when the browser is widened, I want the blockquote to wrap up onto the right of the img, but it only wraps as far as the p element immediately before it.

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <img src="images/image" />
    <p>This is some text.</p>
    <p>Here's some more text.</p>
    <p>And heres yet another block of text.</p>
    <blockquote>This is a quote.</blockquote>
    <a>A link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's an example of how my HTML and CSS look: http://jsfiddle.net/tempertemper/MZWD9/12/

The site that I'm looking to make wider is here: http://tempertemper.net/portfolio

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I can't work out what it is and I'm starting to wonder if float only floats two adjacent elements. I suppose I could put a div around the img and p tags, but I want to keep my HTML nice and clean.

All elements have a width and the blockquote definitely fits in the containing element (ie. the width of the li is sufficient to contain all of the elements and their padding, borders, margins, etc.). I've tried floating all of the elements left, bar the blockquote which I've floated right. Tried using clear:left for the elements preceding the block quote. No joy.

Can anyone put me right?

Thanks,

Martin.

Comment: I could write some if you like. It's a blank canvas at the minute. It's more that I'm wondering if I'm missing a fundamental float rule- maybe you can only float two subsequent HTML elements side by side? I thought you could float multiple elements left then float the last element right and it would sit alongside them, starting at the top of the page where the first element is on the left. Does that make sense? Sorry- it's a bit of a long-winded one!

Comment: Let me know if you still want the CSS. A link to the current page is http://tempertemper.net/portfolio so you can see what it looks like before the page is widened. I want the quote (which is a div with the class "testimonial" on the live site- I've refined it all on my work in progress site) to float to the right of the img.

Comment: No worries, you can float as many elements as you like. Float them all left and they'll all line up on a single line. I'll make an example for you.

Comment: The link to the portfolio gives a 404

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the HTML you have, this is not possible.

The flow of a document happens in HTML order. This means that, under normal circumstances, an element can only affect elements that come *after* it in the HTML, as far as positioning goes.

`float: right`, for example, will move the element to the right and any elements following it will flow around it to the left. `clear: left` will prevent elements from flowing to the left of the element it is applied to.

I might suggest breaking your HTML into blocks, and floating those.

You could then remove the `h3, img, p` selector and rule from your CSS, and replace it with a similar rule for `.content`

In general, I would recommend reading up on document flow, `float`, `clear`, and `position`. They tend to be over-used properties, and it seems you were over-using them here.

Here is the code:

```css
        ul {
            width: 200px;
        }
        .content {
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
        }
        blockquote {
            float: right;
            width: 50px;
        }
        a {
            float: left;
            clear: both;
        }
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <div class="content">
          <img src="images/image" />
          <p>This is some text.</p>
          <p>Here's some more text.</p>
          <p>And heres yet another block of text.</p>
        </div>
        <blockquote>This is a quote.</blockquote>
        <a>A link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Oh, and a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/2bedr/1/

Comment: Do note that, while this alters the HTML, it does not alter the order of the elements, so your multiple-use cases should be preserved.

Comment: Thanks Ryan- I feared it'd be an extra div/section!

Answer (score 4):

The solution is quite simple. Even more simple then you thought.

change:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <img src="images/image" />
    <p>This is some text.</p>
    <p>Here's some more text.</p>
    <p>And heres yet another block of text.</p>
    <blockquote>This is a quote.</blockquote>
    <a>A link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

To this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <blockquote>This is a quote.</blockquote>
    <img src="images/image" />
    <p>This is some text.</p>
    <p>Here's some more text.</p>
    <p>And heres yet another block of text.</p>
    <a>A link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

By stating the blockquote first (and float it right) you first TELL the element to float right. I know this is not logical, but it is the right answer... Had this multiple times myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can float all of your elements left to line them all up horizontally. [Check this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/5xmyS/).

You can also give the `<ul>` a width and float the last element right so it will remain right no matter the width of the parent element. [Another example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/5xmyS/2/).

If there's more I can help with, I will update :)

After your comments, you should revise the HTML structure to have the blockquote directly after the img or title. Then it will behave as you wish. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/MZWD9/13/).

Comment: Hi Kyle, Thanks for your help. I've had a look and it's not doing what I'm after. I've uploaded an example to jsfiddle for you to have a look at: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tempertemper/MZWD9/12/)

Comment: I'd like the "this is a quote" text to sit at the top right, next to Title or the image... Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure I've understood correctly, you want the blockquote to be next to the img when the site is wider?

Comment: that's right, yep. So that it reads as a column down the right hand side of the whole li

Comment: I don't want to alter the HTML if possible as it'll be dual purpose. Triple purpose once I get round to making a smartphone version.