# divs not floating correctly

Tags: html, css, css-float

So I have three divs.
I want them to float like this: 1st /2nd /3rd so all in the same line. With my code it doesnt work. Can you help me?

this is my code: html:

```
 <div id="holder"><h5>something</h5></div>
 <div id="visual_holder">something2</div>
 <div id="invest"><h2>something3</h2></div>

 css:
 #holder{
         width:200px;
          padding-right:48px;
          padding-left:32px;
         padding-top:32px;
        display:inline-block;
           }

    #visual_holder{
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-size:7.5em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    line-height:60%;
     float:right;
    padding-top:32px;
     }

    #invest{float:right;}
```

Thank for your help!

Comment: currently your divs are on 3 seperate lines. You want all in same line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [2 divs floating right wrong aligment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608726/2-divs-floating-right-wrong-aligment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't they be all float left?

See example here and update as needed: http://jsfiddle.net/tRNpQ/

```
#holder{
         width:200px;
          padding-right:48px;
          padding-left:32px;
         padding-top:32px;
       float:left;
           }

    #visual_holder{
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-size:1.5em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    line-height:60%;
     float:left;
    padding-top:32px;
     }

    #invest{float:left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to just exchange the `visual_holder` and `invest` divs:

```
<div id="holder"><h5>something</h5></div>
<div id="invest"><h2>something3</h2></div>
<div id="visual_holder">something2</div>
```

It appears that you have to first put the rightmost div. See also here: [CSS Float multiple left-floated elements and one right floated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243390/css-float-multiple-left-floated-elements-and-one-right-floated)

Answer (score 0):

Just exchange position of your divs like below

```
 <div id="holder"><h5>something</h5></div>   
 <div id="invest"><h2>something3</h2></div>      
 <div id="visual_holder">something2</div>
```